# Register searchUrl for Edge

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

At work a colleague created a registry file which creates some usefull shortcuts for Internet Explorer. However these do not work in Edge and I was wondering if I could create something similar for Edge, but unfortunatly I was unable to find any online resources on this matter.

An example of one of the features is the `g [query]` shortcut which opens the google webpage for the given query:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchUrl\g]
@="http://www.google.com/search?q=%s"
" "="+"
"#"="%23"
"&"="%26"
"?"="%3F"
"+"="%2B"
"="="%3D"
```

Now I know that for google this is redundant if it's the default search engine, but if somebody explains how to create this for google, I can create all the other shortcuts myself.

Comment: I am surprised there is not a lot of information on this. I use IE's SearchUrl feature all the time. I hope they enable it for Edge.

Comment: FYI: This question has more information: https://superuser.com/questions/1264372/microsoft-edge-custom-search-engines-shortcuts-like-chrome.