# <OLD> Microsoft Edge: "Custom Search Engines/Shortcuts" like Chrome

Tags: microsoft-edge

> For anyone just seeing this - the question was regarding the original Microsoft Edge.
> Edge has since changed over to Chromium, and for whatever reason kept the same name.
>
> To make Custom Search Engines in the **newer** Edge (*based on Chromium*):

> [edge://settings/searchEngines](http://edge://settings/searchEngines)

How do I make custom search shortcuts in Microsoft Edge?

For example, In **Google Chrome** I have a custom search to lookup information about an IP address. It's shortcut is "IP"... so to use it, I launch Chrome, and type:

> IP [space] 23.96.52.53

and Chrome will navigate to:

> https://ipinfo.io/23.96.52.53

so, basically performing a search directly on a site, without me needing to remember it's name/address, or needing to click anywhere. I just type a simple shortcut, and my query.

**How can I make perform like this in Edge?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [ticket](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/100457/), it looks like this has been an issue since 2014.

No current word from MS on when or if this will be implemented.

Comment: It looks like it's been addressed since then, if you want to update your answer

Comment: I have updated the question to note that this is regarding Classic Edge from 2017, not the current 2021 version based on Chromium

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone doesn't notice that this question was from "Microsoft Edge" in 2017... but if YOU need the answer for the new *cleverly-named 2019+ product* called "Microsoft Edge":

## For "Microsoft Edge" based on Chromium (since 2019):

Simply go to the new Edge Settings page and you can add the search engine from there. The rest of the steps are now the same as Google Chrome.
[edge://settings/searchEngines](http://edge://settings/searchEngines)